# Using Ruby: Why is my array printing the results then an array of with idex numbers

Tags: arrays, ruby, indexing

I have two methods:

`pwsplayerindex` finds a person that is in an array multiple times and gives the index of where their name is.

`statarray` uses the index # from `pwsplayerindex` to find other data in an array with hashes.

```
def pwsplayerindex(inplayer)
arr = Array.new
pwsarr.each_with_index do |val,index|
if val['player'] == inplayer then arr << index end
end
    arr
end

def statarray(index,stat)
indexarr = Array.new 
pwsplayerindex((pwsarr[index]['player'])).each { |x| puts (pwsarr[x][stat])}   
end  

 print statarray(0,'play')
```

Why does the result yield:

```
51.0
29.9
29.4
28.1
24.6
16.6
[0,82,88,113,192,472]
```

All I want it to give me is:

```
51.0
29.9
29.4
28.1
24.6
16.6
```

Comment: Try and use `[ ]` instead of `Array.new` and also avoid one-lining everything, it makes your code hard to follow. This is also in dire need of proper indentation to make the flow more obvious.

Comment: I apologize for the lack of indentations. I tried the [ ] before hand and it did not help. Thanks.

Comment: Those things don't solve the problem, but they keep your code minimal and organized so errors stand out better. The problem you had here was largely do the `puts` being buried in the middle of a complicated line. Breaking that out on to multiple lines would have made the mistake obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
puts statarray(0,'play')
```

should be just

```
statarray(0,'play')
```

otherwise you print the return value of the function, which is the entire array (because the `each` method)

Comment: Since I am learning Ruby and out of curiosity, if I wanted to use "print' or "puts" how would I go about it?

Comment: print what? I mean, you print your array, element by element, in the statarray method.

Comment: `print` is identical to `puts`, but `puts` merely adds on a newline automatically. That is `print "x\n"` and `puts "x"` are identical in terms of output.

Comment: Ahhh got it. It wasn't registering with me for some reason. Thanks again.

Comment: I don't get what you want to do

Comment: Open another question please

Answer (score 0):

This is what I was shooting for:

```
def pwsplayerindex(inplayer)
arr = []

  pwsarr.each_with_index do |val,index|
    if val['player'] == inplayer then arr << index end
  end
  arr
end

def statarray(i,stat)
indexarr = Array.new

  pwsplayerindex((pwsarr[i]['player'])).each do |x|
    indexarr << pwsarr[x][stat]
  end
    indexarr
end 

puts statarray(0,'play')
```

This gives me what I was aiming for in my original question. It was a simple fix. I didn't realize I was printing in the method.

Comment: Yes, perfect :)